# how get a value from xml tag to hand over to a variable and to compare the value in a for-each loop

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, get, set

i would like to get a value from certain xml tag and hand over to a variable for compare the same value in for-each loop.

I make a screenshot for the xsl code understanding:
[image]

And i make a screenshot for the xml code understanding:

[image]

[Here](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTA/1) is my xsltransform code example.

Here my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<unidatenbank>
    <studenten>
    <student>
        <daten>
            <matrikelnummer>2354444</matrikelnummer>
            <vorname>Horst</vorname>
            <nachname>Wallenstein</nachname>
            <geburtsdatum>09.09.1999</geburtsdatum>
            <studiengang>Politikwissenschaft</studiengang>
        </daten>
        <leistungen>
            <creditpoints>178</creditpoints>
            <noten>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="754125">1.7</note>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="452781">2.7</note>
            </noten>
        </leistungen>
    </student>
    <student>
        <daten>
            <matrikelnummer>2367897</matrikelnummer>
            <vorname>Isabella</vorname>
            <nachname>Gans</nachname>
            <geburtsdatum>08.08.1988</geburtsdatum>
            <studiengang>Politikwissenschaft</studiengang>
        </daten>
        <leistungen>
            <creditpoints>190</creditpoints>
            <noten>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="754125">1.0</note>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="452781">1.7</note>
            </noten>
        </leistungen>
    </student>
    </studenten>
    <veranstaltungen>
        <veranstaltung>
            <veranstaltungsnummer>754125</veranstaltungsnummer>
            <dozent>Prof. Dr. Schnatterberg</dozent>
            <modul>EM 1</modul>
        </veranstaltung>
        <veranstaltung>
            <veranstaltungsnummer>452781</veranstaltungsnummer>
            <dozent>Dr. Hummels</dozent>
            <modul>EM 2</modul>
        </veranstaltung>
    </veranstaltungen>
</unidatenbank>
```

Here is my XSL code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/unidatenbank">
      <xsl:for-each select="//veranstaltungen/veranstaltung">
          <xsl:sort lang="de" select="veranstaltungsnummer"/> 
          <xsl:text>Veranstaltungsnummer: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="./veranstaltungsnummer"/>
          <xsl:variable name="veranstaltungsnummer" select="./veranstaltungsnummer"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
          <ul>
              <xsl:for-each select="//studenten/student">
                  <xsl:sort lang="de" case-order="upper-first" select="./daten/matrikelnummer"/>
                  <li>
                      <xsl:text>Matrikelnummer: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="./daten/matrikelnummer"/>
                      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                      <xsl:text>Note: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="./leistungen/[noten/note=$veranstaltungsnummer]"/>
                      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                      <!--<xsl:text>Gesamtdurchschnitt: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:variable name="leistungen" select="avg(./leistungen/noten/note[])" />
                      <xsl:value-of select="format-number($leistungen, '#.##0,0')"/>-->
                  </li>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </ul>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

hope someone understanding me :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you post the expected result of the transformation, and explain in few words what is the logic you are trying to implement? -- P.S. `xsl:for-each` is not a loop.

Comment: i need this logic: in first for-each get the value from "veranstaltungsnummer" tag  (for the compare) and in the second for-each to get only the same value (at the first for-each) in the attribute "veranstaltungsnummer" from note-tag. Hope you understanding.

Comment: Not really.  It seems to me you need to use a **key** to lookup the related data by matching the `veranstaltungsnummer` values in the two branches - but until you clarify exactly how you want to use the results ... As I said earlier, `xsl:for-each` is not a loop, so there is no "*first for-each*"; that's why your question is difficult to understand.  Explain the "what", not the "how".

Comment: yes that what i need to matching the veranstaltungsnummer. How can i do it ? For the Output i need only the same veranstaltungsnummer number

Comment: Please post the expected output (as code). (2)

Comment: i do it now. I define a variable in the first for-each and use this in the second for-each. but that is not right. What i make wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to define a key `<xsl:key name="vnr" match="studenten/student" use="leistungen/noten/note/@veranstaltungsnummer""/>` then use `<xsl:for-each select="key('vnr', veranstaltungsnummer)">... </xsl:for-each>` to process the students.

`

Comment: Hey Martin, can you please set your code in my xsltransform example: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTA/1 because i don't know to use your logic in my code

Comment: Sorry, I am posting with a tablet where the xsltransform editor does not work. Put the `xsl:key` as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` and then instead of the inner `for-each` use the one in my answer to process only the referenced students.