# how to get a value from a tag in for each group xslt

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

for my defined variable i will get a value from a tag in for each group. This variable i like to use for getting value from another tag.

First i make a screenshot from the xml for the understanding:

[image]

Here a screenshot from my xslt code for the understanding:

[image]

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<unidatenbank>
    <studenten>
    <student>
        <daten>
            <matrikelnummer>2354444</matrikelnummer>
            <vorname>Horst</vorname>
            <nachname>Wallenstein</nachname>
            <geburtsdatum>09.09.1999</geburtsdatum>
            <studiengang>Politikwissenschaft</studiengang>
        </daten>
        <leistungen>
            <creditpoints>178</creditpoints>
            <noten>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="754125">1.7</note>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="452781">2.7</note>
            </noten>
        </leistungen>
    </student>
    <student>
        <daten>
            <matrikelnummer>2367897</matrikelnummer>
            <vorname>Isabella</vorname>
            <nachname>Gans</nachname>
            <geburtsdatum>08.08.1988</geburtsdatum>
            <studiengang>Politikwissenschaft</studiengang>
        </daten>
        <leistungen>
            <creditpoints>190</creditpoints>
            <noten>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="754125">1.0</note>
                <note veranstaltungsnummer="452781">1.7</note>
            </noten>
        </leistungen>
    </student>
    </studenten>
    <veranstaltungen>
        <veranstaltung>
            <veranstaltungsnummer>754125</veranstaltungsnummer>
            <veranstaltungstitel>Einführung in die Politikwissenschaft</veranstaltungstitel>
            <dozent>Prof. Dr. Schnatterberg</dozent>
            <modul>EM 1</modul>
        </veranstaltung>
        <veranstaltung>
            <veranstaltungsnummer>452781</veranstaltungsnummer>
            <veranstaltungstitel>Theorien der Politik</veranstaltungstitel>
            <dozent>Dr. Hummels</dozent>
            <modul>EM 2</modul>
        </veranstaltung>
    </veranstaltungen>
</unidatenbank>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="matrikelnummer" select="2367897"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/unidatenbank"> 
            <xsl:for-each-group select="studenten/student[daten/matrikelnummer=$matrikelnummer]" group-by="daten">
            <xsl:text>Persönlicher Transkript:
            </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="vorname"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="veranstaltungen" group-by="veranstaltung">   
                <xsl:variable name="veranstaltungsnummer" select="./veranstaltungsnummer"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                <xsl:text>Note: 
                </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$veranstaltungsnummer"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="studenten/student">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./leistungen/noten/note[@veranstaltungsnummer=$veranstaltungsnummer]"/>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Here](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFt) is my xsltransform code example.

I will get this output:

```
Persönlicher Transkript:

            2367897
            Isabella
            Gans
            08.08.1988
            Politikwissenschaft

            754125
            Einführung in die Politikwissenschaft
            Prof. Dr. Schnatterberg
            EM 1
        Note: 1.0

            452781
            Theorien der Politik
            Dr. Hummels
            EM 2
        Note: 1.7
```

Comment: Please post your expected output (3).

Comment: **1.** Your example is confusing, because (a) you are grouping by student, your XML has two students, but your result shows only one; (b) why are you grouping by student, when each student has only one record?; and (c) why do you use an example where both students are linked to both  (meetings?)? How will you be able to tell failure from success? -- **2.** Why aren't you using (or at least trying to use) a **key** to link the meetings to the students - as shown in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199680/)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it is not clear why you are trying to group the students when there is (probably) only one record per student, and it looks like you passing in a parameter to get just a specific student anyway. So, you could do just this

```
<xsl:for-each select="studenten/student[daten/matrikelnummer=$matrikelnummer]" >
```

You then group the `veranstaltungen` nodes, but it looks like there is just the one of these, so you probably really mean the child `veranstaltung` elements. Again, it doesn't look like you need to group them. Just do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="veranstaltungen/veranstaltung">
```

In answer to you question, to get the `note` from the `student` you could define a key

```
<xsl:key name="student" match="student" use="daten/matrikelnummer" />
```

Then you would use the key to look up the `note` for the current `veranstaltung` like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('student',string($matrikelnummer))
                      /leistungen/noten/note[@veranstaltungsnummer = $veranstaltungsnummer]" />
```

Try this XSLT (note that to simplify things it is not outputting all fields for the student).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="matrikelnummer" select="2367897"/> 
    <xsl:key name="student" match="student" use="daten/matrikelnummer" />

    <xsl:template match="/unidatenbank"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="studenten/student[daten/matrikelnummer=$matrikelnummer]" >
            <xsl:text>Persönlicher Transkript:&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="daten/vorname"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$matrikelnummer" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="veranstaltungen/veranstaltung">   
            <xsl:variable name="veranstaltungsnummer" select="veranstaltungsnummer"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$veranstaltungsnummer" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Note: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('student', string($matrikelnummer))/leistungen/noten/note[@veranstaltungsnummer = $veranstaltungsnummer]" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having said that, I am not sure you need to iterate over the `veranstaltung` elements at all. You can nest the `xsl:for-each` and iterate over the `note` elements instead. Try this XSLT too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="matrikelnummer" select="2367897"/> 
    <xsl:key name="veranstaltung" match="veranstaltung" use="veranstaltungsnummer" />

    <xsl:template match="/unidatenbank"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="studenten/student[daten/matrikelnummer=$matrikelnummer]" >
            <xsl:text>Persönlicher Transkript:&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="daten/vorname"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$matrikelnummer" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="leistungen/noten/note">   
                <xsl:variable name="veranstaltungsnummer" select="@veranstaltungsnummer"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$veranstaltungsnummer" />
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Note: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```